# BigIntegers to the power of BigInteger (Schnorr signature)

Tags: java, cryptography, biginteger, largenumber

I am trying to implement Schnorr signature algorithm in Java. I faced with problem to calculate power with big exponent (such as MD5 hash number).

Is there any way to get BigInteger in power of BigInteger?

I need to calculate (a^x*b^y) % z where y is extremely large number. Are there any method of calculating such expressions?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/176252

Comment: There's one obvious reason you're having a problem here.  Even a number as small as, say, 42 would take up more memory than exists on the planet if you were to raise it to the (2^127)th power.

Comment: @cHao Since $z$ is relatively small, you only need a few hundred  bytes.

Comment: This is clearly *not* a duplicate of the linked question. Schnorr signatures use modular arithmetic, the linked question states in its title that it's not about modular arithmetic.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Modulus wasn't mentioned in the question when it was first asked.

Comment: @cHao Even the first revision mentioned Schnorr signatures, which are usually implemented in a prime finite field with a few thousand bits. But it's understandable that somebody who isn't a cryptographer misses that part.

Comment: So obviously not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally I found the solution.  I can calculate my expression very fast using this technique:

```
(a * b) % p = ((a % p) * (b % p)) % p
```

So my example will look like this:

```
(a^x * b^y) % z = ( ((a^x) % z) * ((b^y) % z) ) % z;
```

or, using BigInteger in Java:

```
BigInteger result = a.modPow(x, z).multiply( b.modPow(y, z) ).mod(z);
```

Comment: +1 for solving your own problem and for describing the solution. Honestly, I never would've realized that the issue was something so basic -- it's been too long since I first learned modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

For the Schnorr Signature Algorithm, you actually want a combined power and modulus operation.  Just doing a power operation by itself makes no sense, because of the potentially enormous size of the numbers involved.

You need to use the `modPow` method of the [`BigInteger` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Answer (score 1):

No. The maximum value a BigInteger supports is 2<sup>Integer.MAX_VALUE</sup>-1. This clarifying sentence was added to the [BigInteger javadoc](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) in Java 8, but the implementation has been the same for quite a while.

> BigInteger must support values in the range -2<sup>Integer.MAX_VALUE</sup> (exclusive) to +2<sup>Integer.MAX_VALUE</sup> (exclusive) and may support values outside of that range.

As others have pointed out, you may want to use [`modPow`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow-java.math.BigInteger-java.math.BigInteger-) instead of calculating intermediate values.

As a comparison, there are an estimated [10<sup>80</sup>](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=number+of+atoms+in+the+universe) (or 2<sup>265</sup>) atoms in the universe.

Comment: I need to calculate (a^x*b^y) % z where y is extremely large number. Are there any method of calculating such expressions?